# Fixed-Point binary unpacking in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, binaryfiles, unpack

I am struggling with a number-format problem in Python 3.6. My goal is to convert binary data from a file into printable decimal numbers. As an example, I need to convert two little-endian bytes in the form of a byte string...

**b'\x12\00'**

into its big-endian binary form...

**0000000000010010**

and finally to its [16-bit fixed-point Q15](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Q_(number_format)) decimal number form...

**(1 / 4096) + (1 / 16384) = 0.00030517578** (basically, we've made the 2 bytes above human-readable)

In my failed attempts, the struct.unpack function seemed promising, but my low-level / number representation experience just isn't very mature at the moment.

**Failed Attempt:**

```
struct.unpack('<h', b'\x12\x00') # Yields (18,)
```

The above code gets me "18", which would be fine if the bytes represented an integer, but they do not.

Any help / advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The bytes do represent an integer - which has been shifted by 15 bits.  Divide by 32768 (2**15) to get the actual Q15 value.  (This doesn't match the value you calculated, but that's because you did the math wrong - the two set bits actually have place values of 1/2048 and 1/16384.)

Comment: @jasonharper You're right-- nice catch! Your solution works, and I believe I understand your approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @jasonharper in the question comments--

> The bytes do represent an integer - which has been shifted by 15 bits. Divide by 32768 (2**15) to get the actual Q15 value. (This doesn't match the value you calculated, but that's because you did the math wrong - the two set bits actually have place values of 1/2048 and 1/16384.)

I achieved the proper value via the following code--

```
struct.unpack('<h', b'\x12\x00')[0] / (2**15)
```